# Use Java regex to find matching string in middle of a string

Tags: java, regex, string

I need to validate a file input to make sure it has the correct versioning on it. This, for example is the input file: `W:\\folder\\test_v2301_01_29_2014_1420.pfd`

I have built a regex in Java to find the versioning string I am looking for to validate the file.

**RegEx:** `v[0-9]{4}_[0-9]{2}_[0-9]{2}_[0-9]{4}_[0-9]{4}` However, it fails because the regex is looking at the start of the file.

**Called:** `if (!arcvalFileFormBean.getTxtFileReview().matches("v[0-9]{4}_[0-9]{2}_[0-9]{2}_[0-9]{4}_[0-9]{4}"))`

What is the best way to search for the string not knowing how far from the beginning it will be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (!arcvalFileFormBean.getTxtFileReview().matches(
               ".*?v[0-9]{4}_[0-9]{2}_[0-9]{2}_[0-9]{4}_[0-9]{4}.*"))
```

`String#matches` attempts to match complete input therefore `.*?` before your version regex and `.*` after this will make sure that this pattern is matched **anywhere** in the input.

Comment: worked like a charm. Thank you!  I will mark is as the answer in 9 minutes when I can.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of adding leading and trailing match-all arguments to the RegEx, you also could have compiled the pattern first, create a matcher instance and then invoke `find()` on the returned matcher.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("v[0-9]{4}_[0-9]{2}_[0-9]{2}_[0-9]{4}_[0-9]{4}");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(arcvalFileFormBean.getTxtFileReview());

if (!matcher.find()) {
    ...
}
```

Matcher also provides a `matches()` operation though this behaves as the matcher function in String in that it only returns true in case the whole string matches the RegEx pattern.

A Pattern/Matcher construct can be utilized to spot if a certain substring matches the pattern and if so replace certain parts of this string. I.e. we use this approach in order to mask certain passwords in log statements using a customized Logback `CompositeConverter` that contains similar logic like depicted below:

```
Pattern urlAuthPattern = Pattern.compile("//(.*?):.*?@");
Matcher matcher = urlAuthPattern.matcher("ftp://user1:userPW@localhost:21/path/to/somewhere");
if (matcher.find()) {
    // should return ftp://user1:XXX@localhost:21/path/to/somewhere
    return matcher.replaceAll("//$1:XXX@");
}
```